# Rust program works on dev build but segfaults on release build

Tags: rust, ffi, rust-cargo, rust-bindgen

I've written a wrapper for a camera library in Rust that commands and operates a 16-bit camera, and also saves an image to file, using bindgen. Once I command an exposure to start (basically telling the camera to take an image), I can grab the image using a function of the form:

```
pub fn GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(
handle: *mut qhyccd_handle,
w: *mut u32,
...,
imgdata: *mut u16,) -> u32 //(u32 is a retval)
```

In C++, this function was:

```
uint32_t STDCALL GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(qhyccd_handle: *handle, ..., uint8_t *imgdata)
```

In C++, I can pass in a buffer of the form `imgdata = new unsigned char[length_buffer]` and the function would fill the buffer with image data from the camera.

In Rust, similarly, I can pass in a `mut_ptr` of a buffer in the form of a Vec: `let mut buffer: Vec<u16> = vec![0u16; length_buffer]`.

Currently, the way I have structured the code is that there is a main struct, with settings such as the width and height of image, the camera handle, and others, including the image buffer. The struct has been initialized as a `mut` as:

```
let mut main_settings = MainSettings {
width: 9600,
...,
buffer: vec![0u16; length_buffer],
}
```

And when passing it to the `GetQHYCCDSingleFrame` function, I pass it accordingly:

```
let retval = unsafe { GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(main_settings.cam_handle, ..., main_settings.image_buffer.as_mut_ptr()) };
```

This code works perfectly when I build the program with `cargo build` or `cargo build --release` and run using `cargo run` or `cargo run --release`. The program starts the exposure, waits until the exposure is done, and then "gets" the frame and populates the buffer with image data correctly.

However, initially when I was writing the program, I had mistakenly declared the GetQHYCCDSingleFrame function as:

```
pub fn GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(
handle: *mut qhyccd_handle,
w: *mut u32,
...,
imgdata: &mut [u16],) -> u32 //(u32 is a retval)
```

(Note the change in imgdata type from `*mut u16` to `&mut [u16]`).

When I passed in the same previous buffer as a slice and not a pointer:

```
let retval = unsafe { GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(main_settings.cam_handle, ..., &mut main_settings.image_buffer) };
```

the program worked perfectly when I built it with `cargo build` and ran using `cargo run` (dev build with 0 optimizations). The function and call worked, and the image buffer populated. However, the program segfaulted at GetQHYCCDSingleFrame when I built it using `cargo build --release` or ran it using `cargo run --release`  (release build with `opt-level = 3`).

Using `rust-gdb`, the segfault error was:

```
Thread 1 "qsc" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_memmove_sse2_unaligned_erms()
at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:538
538
../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory.
```

I haven't had much experience with Rust optimizations, and don't quite get what optimizations Rust is doing to cause the program to segfault when it runs perfectly with no optimizations. I do understand the correct thing to do is to send in a `mut_ptr` as I do now, and everything works, but looking back, I would like to understand why the previous erroneous program worked but only in dev build and not release build? Is there a possibility it might be understanding the context in the C++ code the requirement there? Or is it something else going on?

If any more information might help understand, I'd be more than happy to provide that as well. Thanks!

Comment: With behavior like the one you describe (works in debug mode, fails in release mode), it's almost always because your code has [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html). The Rust compiler (as well as C and C++ compilers) assumes that your code has no undefined behavior when performing optimizations, which means that some of the optimizations may cause weird behavior and crashes if there in fact _is_ undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Your FFI-function signature is invalid because you use invalid ABI:

```
pub fn GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(
handle: *mut qhyccd_handle,
w: *mut u32,
...,
imgdata: *mut u16,) -> u32 //(u32 is a retval)
```

You should read about FFI first.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html

By default, Rust uses "C" ABI for external functions but you function should use `stdcall` ABI (assuming by your C++ code). You can [read](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html#abi) more about this.

E.g.

```
extern "stdcall" {
 pub fn GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(
   handle: *mut qhyccd_handle,
   w: *mut u32,
   ...,
   imgdata: *mut u16,) -> u32;
}
```